# Кодировка и декодировка изображений Python

Tags: python, кодировка, base64

Вопрос. Я делаю проект и хочу чтобы там отображались изображения без загрузки из интернета. Можно ли закодировать их в текст с помощью Base64 и поместить текст в код, а потом декодировать текст и вставить в кнопки картинки? Если возможно, то подскажите как?

Comment: А почему нельзя поместить в каталог с проектом обычные изображения?

Comment: Можно, ничего не мешает

Comment: Во-первых спасибо! Во-вторых - я делаю приложение которое как можно меньше использует интернет и мегакомпактно и мобильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многие фреймворки хранят изображения в ресурсах. Например pyqt делает файл с переменной в которой содержимое файла просто закодированно base64. В html картинку можно встроить также в base64, но с указанием типа данных спереди.

Comment: Еще более полезный ответ! Спасибо!